# Error "Unable to get issuer certificate local " error while installing browser from Playwright using C# .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, playwright, playwright-dotnet

I get an error while running the command shown below in playwright using

```
powershell bin/Debug/net6.0/playwright.ps1 install
```

> Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
>
> at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1659:34)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
> at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1070:8)
> at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:856:12) {
> code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'

Can anyone provide with the best possible solution?